# Java, Storing JSON Array to class and calling it from other class

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, stringbuilder

I am trying to pull data from class in another class and populate a JPanel with the data,  but it is not working for some reason.

Here is the full restConnector class where I pull the JSON data.
As far as I know this works fine.

```
public class restConnector {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(restConnector.class);

private static final restConnector INSTANCE = new restConnector();


public static restConnector getInstance() {
    return restConnector.INSTANCE;
}

private restConnector(){        
}

private static String user = "ss";
private static String pwd = "ee


public static String encode(String user, String pwd) { 
    final String credentials =  user+":"+pwd; 
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder(); 
    return encoder.encode(credentials.getBytes()); 
} 


//Open REST connection
public static void init() {
    restConnector.LOGGER.info("Starting REST connection...");


    try {

        Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));

        WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://somewebpage.com/

        String url = "activepersonal";






        ClientResponse response = webResource
                    .path("api/alerts/")
                    .queryParam("filter", ""+url)                       
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic "+encode(user, pwd))
                    .header("x-api-version", "1")       
                    .accept("Application/json")
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);


        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {             

        }else{
            restConnector.LOGGER.info("REST connection STARTED.");
        }


        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);       



        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();           
         mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new MyNameStrategy());

         try {
         List<Alert> alert = mapper.readValue(output, new TypeReference<List<Alert>>(){});



         } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();            

      }


}

public void close() {

}
```

}

However, when I try to pull the data in another class it gives me just null values from the system.out.print inside refreshData() method. Here is the code that is supposed to print the data

```
   public class Application{


    Alert alerts = new Alert();


    public Application() {            
        refreshData();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        restConnector.init();
        refreshData();          
    }

    private void refreshData() {
        System.out.println("appalertList: "+alerts.getComponentAt(0));
    }
}
```

Here is my Alert class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Alert {

    private int pasID;
    private String status;
    private boolean shared;
    private String header;
    private String desc;

    public int getPasID() {
        return pasID;
    }

    public void setPasID(int pasID) {
        this.pasID = pasID;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public boolean isShared() {
        return shared;
    }

    public void setShared(boolean shared) {
        this.shared = shared;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }
    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("\n***** Alert Details *****\n");
        sb.append("PasID="+getPasID()+"\n");
        sb.append("Status="+getStatus()+"\n");
        sb.append("Shared="+isShared()+"\n");
        sb.append("Header="+getHeader()+"\n");
        sb.append("Description="+getDesc()+"\n");
        sb.append("*****************************");

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public String getComponentAt(int i) {

        return toString();
    }

}
```

I'm kind a lost with this and been stuck here for a couple of days already so all help would be really appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit: Formatted the code a bit and removed the NullPointerException as it was not happening anymore.

Comment: It would probably help if you could provide the trace for the NullPointerException and let us know which line in your code the NullPointerException occurs on.

Comment: It's this console print :   private void refreshData() {
        System.out.println("appalertList: "+alerts.getComponentAt(0));
    }

Comment: And when I try to print it with System.out.println("appalertList: "+alerts.getHeader());  It gives me an input of:  "appalertList: null
appalertList: null"  The JSON array has two items in it

Comment: In your first bit of code you have this `try { List<Alert> alert..`, but you do absolutely nothing with the newly declared `alert` List. It this where the data is supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Aside from that, there's way too many pieces missing for us to help you debug this. Take some time to edit your post with [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm under the impression that that bit of code is the one that pushes the JSON Array to the Alert.class. Is there something I'm missing there?

Comment: And what makes you think it does that? All it does is read the json, and the `Alert.class` argument is the class type argument, so the mapper know the results should be mapped to the `Alert` attributes. That's how doing `List<Alert>` is possible. The `List<Alert>` is what's returned from the reading, but you have to determine what to actually _do_ with the list. And currently, you do absolutely nothing with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments:

> **Me:** In your first bit of code you have this `try { List<Alert> alert..`, but you do absolutely nothing with the newly declared alert `List<Alert>`. It this where the data is supposed to be coming from?
>
> **OP:** I'm under the impression that that bit of code is the one that pushes the JSON Array to the `Alert.class`. Is there something I'm missing there?
>
> **Me:** And what makes you think it does that? All it does is read the json, and the `Alert.class` argument is the class type argument, so the mapper know the results should be mapped to the `Alert` attributes when it creates the `Alert` objects. That's how doing `List<Alert>` is possible, because passing `Alert.class` decribes `T` in `List<T>`. The `List<Alert>` is what's returned from the reading, but you have to determine what to actually do with the list. And currently, you do absolutely nothing with it

You maybe want to change the class just a bit.

Now this is in no way a good design, just an example of how you can *get it to work*. I would take some time to sit and think about how you want the `restConnector` to be fully utilized

That being said, you can have a `List<Alert> alerts;` class member in the `restConnector` class. And have a getter for it

```
public class restConnector {

    private List<Alert> alerts;
  
    public List<Alert> getAlerts() {
        return alerts;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then when deserializing with the mapper, *assign* the value to `private List<Alert> alerts`. What you are doing is declaring a new locally scoped list. So instead of

```
try {
    List<Alert> alert = mapper.readValue...
```

do this instead

```
try {
    alerts = mapper.readValue
```

Now the class member is assigned a value. So in the `Application` class you can do something like

```
public class Application {

    List<Alert> alerts;
    restConnector connect;

    public Application() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        connector = restConnector.getInstance();
        connector.init();
        alerts = connector.getAlerts();
        refreshData();          
    }   

    private void refreshData() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Alert alert : alerts) {
            sb.append(alert.toString()).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("appalertList: "+ sb.toString());
    }     
}
```

Now you have access to the `Alert`s in the list.

**But let me reiterate: THIS IS A HORRIBLE DESIGN**. For one you are limiting the `init` method to one single call, in which it is only able to obtain *one* and only one resource. What if the rest service needs to access a different resource? You have made the request set in stone, so you cant.

Take some time to think of some good OOP designs where the class can be used for different scenarios.